# Filter Observable array based on FormControl value changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-forms, angular2-observables

I'm trying to use `Observable`s to render two lists of items. One with the complete result, and one with a filtered result.

I have this component:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>

        <input [formControl]="filterControl" />
        <div *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>
    `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    private filterControl = new FormControl();
    private items: Observable<Item[]>;
    private filteredItems: Observable<Item[]>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = this.dataService.get("items");

        this.filteredItems = this.filterControl.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .combineLatest(this.items, (filterValue, items) => {
            return items.filter((item: any) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
        });
    }
}
```

The code will only send one http request, not one per typed filter letter, which is good. The problem is however that no filtered items will show until `filterControl` emits its first value (when I type something in the `input`).

Is there a way to set a default value, or a better way to solve a problem like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `startWith` operator:

```
this.filteredItems = this.filterControl.valueChanges.startWith('')
```

This will ensure that the first value, the default empty string, will be ready

Comment: Thank you! That was easy :) So many new things to learn and not that easy to find the right information.

Comment: Oh yeahhh. rxjs is a great journey. And it is worth investing in it. The more you learn it, the more cleaner, maintainable and efficient your code will become